# issue when access outer function scope in JS

Tags: javascript, scope, executioncontext

Why the following happens?

```
function f1() {
    this.myRefVar = 30;
    this.myRefVar2 = 30;
    var parent = this;

    return function() {
        this.myRefVar = 20;
        console.log('parent contains ' + Object.keys(parent).filter(function(k) {
            return k.indexOf('myRefVar') > -1;
        }));
        console.log('parent value of myRefVar: ' + parent.myRefVar);
        console.log('this value of myRefVar: ' + this.myRefVar);
    };
}

f1()();
```

Output:

```
parent contains myRefVar,myRefVar2
parent value of myRefVar: 20
this value of myRefVar: 20
```

Comment: Just add `"use strict";` to `f1` and see what happens.

Comment: I think I understand now, using `this` inside a function (not a `constructor` now object `method`) is the same as defining a variable without using `var`, which is a bad thing, because this makes the variable refer to the global scope, not the function local scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because there is actually no scoping here. All of `this` accesses refer to the `window` object. Hence, when you are editing `this.myRefVar` at the inner scope, you are actually editting the value at the `window`.

```
var theName = "SO";
var myObject = function(){
    this.theName = "SO2";
    this.foo = function() {
        this.theName = "SO3";
    }
}
```

> Here, I defined some variables, and functions. The variable `theName`, first declared at `root(window)` scope, then inside `myObject` scope (There is no scope like this, just for the explanation, and then inside `foo` scope.)

```
console.log(theName); // SO
console.log(this.theName); // SO
console.log(window.theName); // SO
console.log(myObject.theName); // undefined
console.log(myObject.foo); // undefined
console.log(this.foo); // undefined
console.log(window.foo); // undefined
```

> And here, I am trying to access `theName` variable via different ways. If there is actually scopping here 4th one should work after function call. The others just representing same idea, but different way.

```
myObject();

console.log(theName); // SO2
console.log(this.theName); // SO2
console.log(window.theName); // SO2
console.log(myObject.theName); // undefined
console.log(myObject.foo); // undefined
console.log(this.foo); // function myObject/this.foo()
console.log(window.foo); // function myObject/this.foo()
```

> After function call, I still can't access `myObject.theName` as I hoped. That's because, calling it this way `myObject.theName` does not actually accessing `myObject` scope, rather than I am trying to access `theName` property of `myObject` function. And, without actually defining/instantiating/creating this function as an object, I cannot access the properties.

```
myObject.theName;// undefined. Accessing myObject as a function
new myObject().theName // SO2. Accessing an object derived from myObject.
```

What's going on in your code is actually not scopping but closure. For better understanding:
[Scopping](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp)
[Closures](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_closures.asp)
[Similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

Comment: I like your answer, however I couldn't understand all of the examples you put.

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript function have global scope
For example

```
function parent() {
  var self_parent = this;
  function firstChild() {
    var self_first_child = this;
    function childOfChild() {
        var self_child_of_child = this;
    }
  }
}
```

in the above code following will be true

```
self_parent === self_first_child === self_child_of_child
```

for more Info see [JavaScript-Garden-About-this](http://bonsaiden.github.io/JavaScript-Garden/#function.this)